# Can I implicitly pass attributes of an object to one of its other attributes in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I'm trying to do is something like

```
class my_class:
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = attribute_class()
        self.bar.some_function()

class attribute_class:
    def __init__(self):
        # This is where I don't know what I have to write
    def some_function(self):
        do_something_with(foo)
```

Of course I could pass the `my_class` object to the `attribute_class` object in its init function, but that would be a bit silly. I could also pass the needed attributes, but since python doesn't know pointers, this will create redundant information. Furthermore, the "child's" attribute won't automatically change when the "parent's" does.

Comment: If you want `attribute_class`  to know about `my_class`, why is it silly to pass it? Perhaps you have a design problem?

Comment: Some problems fit well with a class (hierarchy) like e.q. GUI toolkits. Other problems don't "fit" well into classes. Questions like this can be a sign that classes are not a good fit for your problem domain.

Comment: @kabanus If I pass it, won't it create a copy of all the data in the parent object? That is what I'm trying to avoid

Comment: No, it will not. Python passes references, not copies except for primitives.

Comment: Oh, I was not aware of this! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python functions are in general closures, i.e. they can capture context.
For example:

```
In [1]: class Foo: 
   ...:     def __init__(self, x): 
   ...:         self.data = x 
   ...:         def getter(): 
   ...:             return self.data 
   ...:         def setter(y): 
   ...:             self.data = y 
   ...:         self.getter = getter 
   ...:         self.setter = setter 
   ...:                                                                                                                                   

In [2]: x = Foo(12)                                                                                                                       

In [3]: x.getter()                                                                                                                        
Out[3]: 12

In [4]: y = x.getter                                                                                                                      

In [5]: z = x.setter                                                                                                                      

In [6]: y()                                                                                                                               
Out[6]: 12

In [7]: z(42)                                                                                                                             

In [8]: y()                                                                                                                               
Out[8]: 42
```

Note that it would help know what you're trying to do as there are probably better ways instead of having functions (closures) as attributes...

Comment: So you suggest passing the getter to the child object? That might actually work, thanks!

Comment: @JakobFilser: No... I am saying that functions can capture context in Python so there are many possibilities. To try to find a good Python solution however it would help to understand what you are trying to do and why... there are probably better (more pythonic) solutions.

Comment: The information that python passes references rather than data (see comments above) together with your hint actually solves this, thanks again!

Comment: @JakobFilser: Yeah... you said there are no pointers in Python when in reality you ONLY have pointers. Even in `x = 3` under the hood `x` contains a pointer to an object that contains the number `3` :-)